# Android create RSA 1024 .NET compatible keys

Tags: android, rsa

I am developing an Android Application and I need to generate some RSA private and public keys to use for secure communication with web services. To do this I need to have the public key in a .NET compatible form. 
Like:

```
<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>{0}</Modulus><Exponent>{1}</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>
```

So far I managed to to this:

```
  keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
  keyGen.initialize(1024);
  keypair = keyGen.genKeyPair();
  privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
  publicKey = keypair.getPublic();

  // Get the bytes of the public and private keys
  byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
  byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

I've got no clue how to continue. Could you please provide some help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody else interested, a very good tutorial can be found in here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/porting_java_public_key.aspx?msg=3407475

If you need Base64 encoding/decoding, because it's not included in Android (at least in API 4) you could use the class from here: iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the type `publicKey`. If is not already, you should cast to an `RSAPublicKey`, then use the `getPublicExponent()` and `getModulus()` methods to extract the BigInteger. Then simply use standard Java IO, e.q. `PrintStream.println()` or `printf()` to generate the XML components.

Comment: To serialize this into `<RSAKeyValue>` (which is presumably comes from the XML Digital Signature format), you also need to base64-encode the values obtained from `getPublicExponent()` and `getModulus()`, not just use `toString()` directly.

Comment: @Bruno: thanks, I was not familiar with the spec and just guessed about what was needed for {0} and {1}.